# Rotating a star around one of its points on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am converting a flash animation to javascript/html5.  I have my animation looking pretty similar, however, I am struggling to accomplish a rotation on a star I am drawing on an html5 canvas.  I am using a variation of the code from this website: http://programmingthomas.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/drawing-stars-with-html5-canvas/ For reference, I have pasted the relevant code below.

```
function star(ctx, x, y, r, p, m)
{
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0-r);
    for (var i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / p);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - (r*m));
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / p);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - r);
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

I have figured out how to rotate the star around its center by inserting a `ctx.rotate()` call, like so:

```
    ...beginPath();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(radianOffset);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0-r);
    for (var i = 0...
```

Does anybody have any clues how to rotate the star around one of its points?  I have been reading about the rotate function, but cannot figure out how to make it work with my star function.

Comment: Rotating around an arbitrary point is just a rotation plus a translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just translate to the the point you want to rotate around, rotate and then translate back continuing the drawing of the star.

However, with the function you're using this may turn out to be a little more complex than just that as you would need the absolute position of the point for the star "spikes".

Here is an alternative implementation I wrote to draw deal with this. Here we call a function to get an array with the points in order to build a star.

We can then use that point array to chose a pivot point for rotation as well as rendering the star itself. The function looks like this:

```
// cx = center x
// cy = center y
// r1 = outer radius
// r2 = inner radius
// spikes = number of star "spikes"
function getStarPoints(cx, cy, r1, r2, spikes) {

  var i = 0,
      deltaAngle = (2 * Math.PI) / spikes,
      x, y,
      points = [];

  // calc rest of points
  for (; i < spikes; i++) {
    points.push(
      {
        x: cx + r2 * Math.cos(deltaAngle * i),               // calc inner point
        y: cy + r2 * Math.sin(deltaAngle * i)
      }, {
        x: cx + r1 * Math.cos(deltaAngle * i + deltaAngle * 0.5), // outer point
        y: cy + r1 * Math.sin(deltaAngle * i + deltaAngle * 0.5)
      }
    );
  }

  return points;
}
```

Now all we need to do is to pick a point from the array which would be a point object, and use that for center of rotation, here point index 1:

```
ctx.translate(points[1].x, points[1].y);   // translate to origin for rotation
ctx.rotate(angle);                         // rotate angle (radians)
ctx.translate(-points[1].x, -points[1].y); // translate back
```

Then render the star

```
ctx.beginPath();                           // start a new path
ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);      // starting point
for(var i = 1, p; p = points[i++];)
    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);                  // add points to path
ctx.fill();                                // close and fill
```

Note: if you want to stroke the star you would need a `closePath()` before stroking.

That's it. See snippet below for an animated version of this as well as full source.

Performance wise this would be faster as well as we calculate the star only once, and in this case we do not use save/restore (which are somewhat costly operations) for the animation.

Hope this helps!

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    points = [],
    angleStep = 0.025;

ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';

// draw first star at angle 0 and get point array
points = getStarPoints(150, 90, 80, 40, 5);

// now that we know the point for each part, lets animate
loop();

function loop() {

  // clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  // rotate around one of the points (or anywhere if wanted..)
  ctx.translate(points[1].x, points[1].y);
  ctx.rotate(angleStep);
  ctx.translate(-points[1].x, -points[1].y);

  // draw start
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for(var i = 1, p; p = points[i++];) ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
  ctx.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

// Star by Ken Fyrstenberg/CC3.0-Attr
// cx = center x
// cy = center y
// r1 = outer radius
// r2 = inner radius
// spikes = number of star "spikes"
function getStarPoints(cx, cy, r1, r2, spikes) {

  var i = 0,
      deltaAngle = (2 * Math.PI) / spikes,
      x, y,
      points = [];

  // calc rest of points
  for (; i < spikes; i++) {
    points.push(
      {
        x: cx + r2 * Math.cos(deltaAngle * i),
        y: cy + r2 * Math.sin(deltaAngle * i)
      }, {
        x: cx + r1 * Math.cos(deltaAngle * i + deltaAngle * 0.5),
        y: cy + r1 * Math.sin(deltaAngle * i + deltaAngle * 0.5)
      }
    );
  }

  return points;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: Many many times thank you  That is one of the best answers I have ever seen.  Thank you for being so thorough.